# Deleting a range of nodes in c++

Tags: c++, linked-list

Hello all I am new to here and relatively to programming as well. I am trying to delete a range of nodes in a linked list but cannot figure out how to do so.  I tried using a for loop, however since I am passing my delete function a string, I can not increment the node to make it delete up to the final count.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
 #include <iostream>
    #define nullptr 0
    #include <cstdlib>
    #include <algorithm>
    #include <string>
    #include <conio.h>



    using namespace std;
    int menu();

    class ItemList {
        private:
            struct ListNode{
                string IName;
                string QQuantity;
                string PPrice;
                double value;
                struct ListNode * next;
                    };
    ListNode *head;
        public:
            ItemList()
                {
                    head = new ListNode;
                    head->next=nullptr;
                }
                ~ItemList();

                void insertNode(string Item, string Quantity, string Price)
                {
                    ListNode *newNode;
                    ListNode *nodePtr;
                    ListNode *previousNode=nullptr;

                    newNode=new ListNode;
                    newNode->IName=Item;
                    newNode->QQuantity=Quantity;
                    newNode->PPrice=Price;

                    if(!head)
                    {
                        head=newNode;
                        newNode->next=nullptr;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        nodePtr=head;
                        previousNode=nullptr;

                        while(nodePtr != nullptr && nodePtr->IName < Item)
                        {
                            previousNode=nodePtr;
                            nodePtr=nodePtr->next;
                        }
                        if(previousNode==nullptr)
                        {
                            head=newNode;
                            newNode->next=nodePtr;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            previousNode->next=newNode;
                            newNode->next=nodePtr;
                        }
                    }
                }
                void displayNode()
                {
                    ListNode *nodePtr;
                    nodePtr=head->next;

                    while(nodePtr)
                    {
                        cout << nodePtr->IName << ",  ";
                        cout << nodePtr->QQuantity << "  ";
                        cout << "$" << nodePtr->PPrice << "\n" << endl;
                        nodePtr=nodePtr->next;
                    }
                }
                void modifyNode(string Item)
                {
                ListNode *nodePtr;
                ListNode *nodePrev;
                string newName, newQuantity, newPrice;
                int modify;
                if (!head)
                {
                    return;
                    cout << "Store is empty." << endl;
                }
                else
                {
                    nodePtr = head;
                    if (head->IName==Item)
                        nodePtr = head->next;
                    else
                    {
                        while (nodePtr != nullptr && nodePtr->IName != Item)
                        {
                            nodePrev = nodePtr;
                            nodePtr = nodePtr->next;
                        }
                    }
                    if (nodePtr)
                    {
                        cout << nodePtr->IName << "\t" << nodePtr->QQuantity << "\t" << nodePtr->PPrice << endl;
                        cout << "What would you like to change?\n";
                        cout << "1. Item" << endl;
                        cout << "2. Quantity" << endl;
                        cout << "3. Price" << endl;
                        cout << "4. Whole Entry" << endl;
                        cin >> modify;

                        transform(newName.begin(), newName.end(), newName.begin(), ::toupper);
                        switch (modify)
                        {
                            case 1:
                                cout << "Change to what?\n";
                                cin >> newName;
                                nodePtr->IName = newName;
                                break;
                            case 2:
                                cout << "Change to what?\n";
                                cin >> newQuantity;
                                nodePtr->QQuantity = newQuantity;
                                break;
                            case 3:
                                cout << "Change to what?\n";
                                cin >> newPrice;
                                nodePtr->PPrice = newPrice;
                                break;
                            case 4:
                                cout << "Change to what?\n";
                                cin >> newName;
                                nodePtr->IName = newName;
                                cout << "Change to what?\n";
                                cin >> newQuantity;
                                nodePtr->QQuantity = newQuantity;
                                cout << "Change to what?\n";
                                cin >> newPrice;
                                nodePtr->PPrice = newPrice;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                        cout << "Person not found\n";
                }
            }

                void deleteNode(string Item)
                {
                    ListNode *nodePtr;
                    ListNode *previousNode;

                    if(!head)
                        return;
                    if(head->IName==Item)
                    {
                        nodePtr=head->next;
                        delete head;
                        head=nodePtr;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        nodePtr=head;
                        while(nodePtr!=nullptr && nodePtr->IName!=Item)
                        {
                            previousNode=nodePtr;
                            nodePtr=nodePtr->next;
                        }
                        if(nodePtr)
                        {
                            previousNode->next=nodePtr->next;
                            delete nodePtr;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            cout << "Nothing to delete." << endl;
                        }
                    }
                }
            };


    ItemList::~ItemList()
    {
        ListNode *nodePtr;
        ListNode *nextNode;

        nodePtr=head;
        while(nodePtr!=nullptr)
        {
            nextNode=nodePtr->next;
            delete nodePtr;
            nodePtr=nextNode;
        }
    }

    int main()
    {
        ItemList pro;
        int method;
        while(method!=0)
        {
        int method=menu();
        system("cls");
        string It, Q, P;
        switch(method)
        {
        case 1:
            int count;
            cout << "How many products would you like to put in?" << endl;
            cin >> count;
            system("cls");
            for(int i=0; i<count; i++)
            {
                cout << "Product #" << i + 1 << endl;
                cout << "Enter the item name: ";
                cin.sync();
                getline(cin,It);
                transform(It.begin(), It.end(), It.begin(), ::toupper);
                cout << "Enter the Quantity: ";
                cin >> Q;
                transform(Q.begin(), Q.end(), Q.begin(), ::toupper);
                cout << "Enter the Price: ";
                cin >> P;
                pro.insertNode(It, Q, P);
                cout << "\n";
            }
            break;

        case 2:
            pro.displayNode();
            break;

        case 3:
            pro.displayNode();
            cout << "What product do you wish to modify? (by item name)" << endl;
            cin.sync();
            getline(cin, It);
            transform(It.begin(), It.end(), It.begin(), ::toupper);
            system("cls");
            pro.modifyNode(It);
            break;

        case 4:
            int del;
            cout << "Do you wish to delete one product or more?" << endl;
            cout << "1. One" << endl;
            cout << "2. Range of Products" << endl;
                cin >> del;
                system("cls");
                switch(del)
                {
                    case 1:
                        cout << "What product do you wish to delete? (by item name)" << endl;
                        pro.displayNode();
                        cout << "\n";
                        cin.sync();
                        getline(cin,It);
                        transform(It.begin(), It.end(), It.begin(), ::toupper);
                        pro.deleteNode(It);
                        cout << "\n";
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        int count;
                        cout << "How many?";
                        cin >> count;
                        pro.displayNode();
                        cout << "Starting where?" << endl;
                        cin >> It;
                        transform(It.begin(), It.end(), It.begin(), ::toupper);
                        for(int i=0; i<count; i++)
                        {
                            pro.deleteNode(It);
                            It(i);
                        }
                        break;
                }
            break;

        case 5:
            pro.~ItemList();
            cout << "All items deleted." << endl;
            break;

        case 0:
            cout << "Exiting the program." << endl;
            return 0;
        }
        system("pause");
        system("cls");
        }
        return 0;
    }

    int menu()
    {
        string space1= "                    ";
        string space2= "                                  ";
        int method;
        cout << space1 << "What would you like to do to the Phone Book?" << endl;
        cout << space2 << "1. Insert" << endl;
        cout << space2 << "2. Display" << endl;
        cout << space2 << "3. Modify" << endl;
        cout << space2 << "4. Delete" << endl;
        cout << space2 << "5. Empty" << endl;
        cout << space2 << "0. Exit\n" << endl;
        cout << space2;
        cin >> method;
        return(method);
    }
```

Comment: Define deleting a range of nodes, an example would also help clarify.

Comment: Why not send the count to deleteNode() function and do the for loop there. What do you expect **"It(i);"** will do in your delete loop?

Comment: For example, if i wanted to delete node "Ball" up to node "doll" in one go

Answer (score 0):

Instead of deleting by node's name (IName), you can make a function that retrieves the node pointer of a given name and then change your 'deleteNode' function to one that deletes by pointer instead of name. Also, this function should return the next node pointer (or null if there isn't another element in the list) that you could use to delete the subsequent nodes.

**EDIT:** very basic code example:

```
char * get_pointer_by_name(string Name)
{
    ListNode * curr_node = this->head;

    while(curr_node != NULL)
    {
        if(curr_node->IName == Name)
        {
            return (char *) curr_node;
        }
        else
        {
            curr_node = curr_node->next;
        }
    }

    // node not found

}

char * delete_node(char * pointer)
{
    char * tmp = (char *) (ListNode *) pointer->next; // check this, it may be wrong
    // this is a very simple and illustrative way to delete your node, not the right one
    delete pointer;
    // return the next node pointer
    return tmp;
}
```

Once this is done, all you have to do is get the node that you want to delete with get_pointer_by_name() and iterate a few times to delete the remaining nodes, just like this:

```
char * tmp = get_pointer_by_name("name");

while(tmp != NULL && count > 0)
{
    tmp = deleteNode(tmp);
    count--;
}
```